# Angular8 - Getting data to an autocomplete from an API endpoint

Tags: angular, typescript, autocomplete, angular-material, angular8

I'm trying to make an autocomplete to be fed by an API rest response (instead of a local array).

This is how my code is right now:

TS component:

```
public filteredAddressees: Observable < Addressee[] > ;
public addresseesCtrl = new FormControl();

[...]

displayFnAddressee(): string | undefined {
  return undefined;
}

private _filterAddressees(value: string): Observable < Addressee[] > {
  console.log(`_filterAddressees(${value})`);
  return this.addresseeService.getFilteredList(value.toLocaleLowerCase()).pipe(
    map((response: any) => {
      return response.items;
    })
  );
}

getFilteredAddressees() {
  console.log(`GetFilteredAddressees(${this.addresseesCtrl.value})`);
  this.filteredAddressees = this.addresseesCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    debounceTime(500),
    switchMap(val => {
      console.log(`switchMap(${val})`);
      document.getElementById('noFocus').blur();
      return this._filterAddressees(val || '');
    }));
}

selChangedAddressee(e: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
  this.addAddressee(e.option.value);
}
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <input matInput id="noFocus" placeholder="Add user" (click)="getFilteredAddressees()" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="addresseesCtrl">
  <mat-autocomplete (optionSelected)="selChangedAddressee($event)" id="autocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFnAdressee" #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let addressee of filteredAdressees | async" [value]="addressee">
      {{ addressee.name }} {{ addressee.surname }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

But aparently it never reaches the switchMap instruction, and if I change the input value it also doesn't catch the formControl valueChange event.

However, if I catch the form value change like this, it reacts each time I change the value:

```
this.addresseesCtrl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        console.log('value changed', val);
    });
```

In browser console I don't get any kind of error message.

Comment: Does it hit your `console.log`s as you expect?

Comment: It reaches the first console.log, the "GetFilteredAddressees(value)" one, but it doesn't get to the "switchMap(value)"

Comment: It was just a typo. There is nothing wrong with your code. In your code, you wrote `filteredAddressees` but in html you wrote `filteredAdressees`

Comment: Ohhh my god... thank you so much, I'm utterly blind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by @bunyamin-coskuner:

> was just a typo. There is nothing wrong with your code. In your code, you wrote filteredAddressees but in html you wrote filteredAdressees